# Create a function curve template

Tags: pspicture

What is the best way to make this figure including the grid, color, axes, and curve name so I can do the same for any other function?

***f(x) = (x+2)^3***

[image]

The one I have for the moment, not corresponding to what I want...

```
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-1)(2.5,5)
\psset{xunit=1 cm, algebraic=true}
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-2.5,-1)(2.5,5)
\psplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt]{-2}{2}{(x+2)^2}
\end{pspicture}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Tikz, you can plot any kind of data with data visualisation.
https://tikz.dev/dv

You can see in the example here https://tikz.dev/dv-main that it accepts a polynomial function.

You can easily dig in this section of the  section of the manual to find the adequate solution to your problem.